# Can you get a folder name without the user needing to upload the files?

Tags: html, input

I want to enable the user of my webpage to use the file browser to select a folder and get its name. The only way I have found so far is to use `<input type="file" webkitdirectory/>` and then get the folder name from the files. However, you still need to upload the files first, which is unnecessary and confusing to the user. Is there any way to get the name of a folder without needing to upload the files first?

Comment: Try this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showDirectoryPicker

Comment: @Justinas Sounds good. No Firefox support is rough though. But I will keep an eye on it, thanks.